# Angular 8 ignores includePaths

Tags: angular

I have a monorepo Angular project. I want to make it easier to import `variables.scss`, because otherwise I have to go up multiple times.

The project structure is next

```
projects
-- myApp
  -- src
    -- scss
      -- _variables.scss
```

What I've done so far is I placed in `angular.json` `icnludePaths`

```
...
"myApp": {
  ...
  "root": "projects/myApp",
  "sourceRoot": "projects/myApp/src",
  "architect": {
    "build" {
      ...
      "options": {
        ...
        "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
          "includePaths": ["src/scss"]
      }
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Then I specify in component's styles

```
@import "variables"
```

The PhpStorm is fine with that and shows no errors, however when I build my project there is an error that sass loader cannot resolve `@import "variables"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The includePaths array takes absolute paths, so just change "src/scss" to "projects/myApp/src/scss" and it should work.